A short fiction about angels appearing and causing both miracles and disasters
About 15 or 20 years ago, I read in a collection a complicated short story (or maybe novelette) in which angels sometimes appear. It takes place in a world not very different from ours, apart from these apparitions. When they appear, the angels do cure some people who are ill or crippled, but also cause destructions, cripple some healthy people and cause the death of others. What is remarkable about those casualties is that surviving bystanders can see whether the people killed go to Heaven or Hell.
The story is about a few people whose lives were very much affected by such apparitions, but that is all I can remember.

This is surely not what you want, but essentially 100% of this description applies to a number of holy texts of major religions, including the book of Genesis.

@DanielMcLaury  LOL ! But fez is right, it is the novelette by Ted Chiang. One can hardly call the book of Genesis "a short story or maybe a novelette".

If you were to publish the book of Genesis by itself it's well within the limits of what would be considered a short story, and it is an episodic narrative.

Sounds like Hell Is the Absence of God by Ted Chiang. It is a novelette that was released in 2001.
Quoting from Wikipedia, emphasis on the points that match the question:

The story is set in a world where the existence of God, souls, Heaven, and Hell are obvious and indisputable, and where miracles and angelic visitations are commonplace—albeit not necessarily benevolent. The story focuses primarily on Neil Fisk, a widower whose wife, Sarah, is killed by the collateral damage of an angel's visitation. Sarah's soul was seen ascending to Heaven, leading the non-devout Neil to desperately seek the love and devotion needed to please God and enter Heaven to reunite with Sarah.
The story also follows Janice Reilly, a woman born without legs who is made able-bodied in an angelic visitation. [...]
The reader is then introduced to Ethan Mead, who cannot discern the meaning of an angelic encounter he experienced. [...]


This question is better and the answer is at least as good so I closed the other one as a duplicate of this one.
